# Do I need to check the box Backwards Compatibillity (AppCompat) in Android Studio 3.2.1?

Tags: android, android-studio

I plan to design a new APP which minimum SDK is API 21, I hope to use latest AndroidX library.

Do I need to check the box Backwards Compatibillity (AppCompat) in Android Studio 3.2.1 ?

**Image 1**

[image]

**Image 2**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. You can use it without checking this box.

Backwards Compatibillity is for your application to appear the same in older versions. In case the minimum version is API 21 I still think you should use Backwards Compatibillity, because over time this version will be deprecated and then you will have to support it for a unique look.

From Android Developer page

> Support Libraries provide additional convenience classes and features
>   not available in the standard Framework API for easier development and
>   support across more devices.

So, answering your question: Yes. Because API 21 will soon become old, and you will need to support them.

You can also read more on the official webiste: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/